# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am unable to install packages due to the error below:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-unpack-3v6gctq6\\pyinstaller-5.7.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl'
```

[image: error screenshot]

I've tried reinstalling Python. Plus, I've tried practically everything.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, temporarily disabling Windows Defender helped

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution helped me a lot. I had been searching Google for like 4 hours before I went on here.